# cut cylinder shape in to 2 parts

Tags: 3d, maya

i'm very new to MAYA [version-2013] .i need to create 3d threaded rod for mechanical simulation .i found [nicely modeled 3d  nail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmWcy_weZw2S01sbGxXQ29VX00/view?usp=sharing) and i know i can take a rod by removing head of the nail so i want to know how to cut nail to remove head section.i was following tutorials ,videos about 12 hours .still i didn't able to remove head.i want to know how to cut and remove head part of nail.

this is preview of nail

[image]
[image]

Comment: Although we *do* have `3d` and `maya` categories, there's few users with 3d expertise on this site. Your question migth fare better at [the Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Vincent but i cannot even add maya tag on blender exchange

Comment: Eh :(. I flagged your question for mod attention, I hope they'll know what to do with it.

Comment: @Vincent, nope not many of us. Thank god for email notifications!

Comment: @mhlester Great! Good to know you're around! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple options.

---

The first is likely the easiest for a beginner level, but can cause the occasional geometry artifact depending on topology.

- Create a cube
- Position it to overlap the part of the screw you want to keep
- Select the screw and the cube
- (Polygons Menu) > *Mesh > Booleans > Intersection*

---

The second option is to do it manually. This can become more difficult with complex geometry, but your screw looks easy enough.

- Select the screw
- Press *F11* to switch to face selection (or *Select > Face*)
- Marquee select the faces that make up the head of the screw
- Delete the selected faces (*Delete* key)
- Fill the hole using (Polygons Menu) > *Mesh > Fill Hole*

Answer (score -1):

#### Answer:

Look up component selection mode on Google. You will have to view the object in component mode (with polygon faces visible), select those faces and delete them.

#### A word of advice:

People go to school for doing 3D. It takes a good bit of training. I would suggest looking up basic modeling tutorials in Maya. That will give you an idea of basic operations to do to get what you want.

Hope this helps someone. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Although sound advice, this does not answer the question and would be better as a comment. Thanks for chipping in, though!

Comment: @vincent, The first paragraph _is_ the answer. Mhlester gave a better tutorial of it. The second para was a sincere advice out of goodwill as to how the OP can get better at this and avoid future obstacles of similar nature, an advice to fish rather than giving it away. I dont understand yhe purpose of 2 down votes. Anyway not here for the points. Hope this helps whoever.